# How can I optimize this Macro execute faster for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnRXbKsqzF99AcG-M5JJIipBQ-sjlSuzEQAeXZ6fq0I/edit?usp=sharing

I have an inventory system where the user uses SHIFT + CTRL + ALT + 1 to generate the format and drop down menus for a receiving log.

I know next to nothing about coding, please explain like i'm dumb.

I was hoping that moving the order of some commands around or applying multiple colors and drop downs at the same time would shorten run time but i don't know what i'm doing.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: to speed up execution time. 

it takes about 3-4 seconds to run, i'm hoping it can be made faster.

Comment: I don't think I know enough about sheets/coding to understand what answers you need. but don't worry about it. joe joe gave me a faster running script that i can edit to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to see the macro but in google Sheets you can add a menu button at the top that users can click to run any of your macros.

```
function onOpen(){
    initMenu();

    }
    function initMenu(){

    var menuItems = [
      { name: 'New Packing Slip', functionName: 'NewPackingSlip'},
      { name: 'Add More Items', functionName: 'MoreItems'},
      { name: 'Add Blank Row', functionName: 'BlankRow'}
    ];
     SpreadsheetApp.getActive().addMenu('More', menuItems);
};

function NewPackingSlip(){}
function MoreItems(){}
function BlankRow(){}
```

Comment: sorry about that, i assumed the script would be accessible to everyone automatically here is a doc link that i paste'd them in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_ch4ynL_idEl69d9r9FrddersPgLDRAPSAhy_hkC6p0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KyleKelly This this and see if it works. It will make a button on the toolbar for you.

https://pastebin.com/i4MpHH2G

This will reduce a lot of calls that aren't needed but I can't tell if it will work or not. I'm missing your sheet so it's hard to tell. If you get errors let me know.

Comment: this had some errors, rows 7-10 are what happens when i run your scrip (which thank you is fast). the format i'm aiming for is rows 4-6. i'm trying to figure out how to give access to everything here are some more links 

script ID 1NMc3JWz3_WpJn2lWbrEsddH-xfplry2beB0DRxOa2L9Pn0YMqyHE2T1T
oringial macro: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_ch4ynL_idEl69d9r9FrddersPgLDRAPSAhy_hkC6p0/edit
demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnRXbKsqzF99AcG-M5JJIipBQ-sjlSuzEQAeXZ6fq0I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: deployment id AKfycbwr6br_QkBZblUBNAPrcC5XCRp6STrzHgNhyjll_HCCBUKKGrzzhPGYLglnPRlmntoc

script website 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwr6br_QkBZblUBNAPrcC5XCRp6STrzHgNhyjll_HCCBUKKGrzzhPGYLglnPRlmntoc/exec

Comment: @KyleKelly okay I've updated your script to open and install the menu when the spreadsheet is opened. It does take it a few seconds but it will be there. Also updated the menu and it works now too.
 
https://pastebin.com/i4MpHH2G

Comment: thank you very much, it still has some problems but don't worry about it. i think i can figure out how to adjust it to my sheet. also the menu was never part of what i requested but it's a nice addition thank you!